# Error 'could not translate host name' running Laravel migration in Docker PostgreSQL container

Tags: docker, laravel-8

Well, I have a container with PostgreSQL that I connect to from Laravel showing records on the screen. The Laravel container access the PostgreSQL data ok. This is the result:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#463 (2) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#466 (3) {
      ["pru_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["pru_name"]=>
      string(5) "george"
      ["pru_years"]=>
      int(45)
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#467 (3) {
      ["pru_id"]=>
      int(2)
      ["pru_name"]=>
      string(5) "paul"
      ["pru_years"]=>
      int(30)
    }
  }               
}
```

So far very good!

But when I try to run migrations, with `php artisan migrate`, I get:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "pgcontainer" to address: Name or service not known

Checking the connection, **the db_host**: (`pgcontainer`)

```
'pgsql' => [
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'pgcontainer'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mydatabase'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'myuser'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypass'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'schema' => 'public',
    'sslmode' => 'prefer',
],
```

I tried to modify the host, because I understand what it does not recognize, changing `pgcontainer` for `127.0.0.1`, but when doing it two interesting things happen:

1. **ON THE SCREEN:** It no longer shows the records on the screen, because the Laravel container no longer accesses the PostgreSQL:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432

2. **SSH - PHP ARTISAN MIGRATE:** Now Laravel can see the PostgreSQL container but it cannot authenticate (the password is correct since before it shows records on the screen):

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "mydatabase"

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have one container with Postgres, and a different container with Laravel.  The connection from the Laravel -> Postgres containers works fine.

The error you are seeing suggests you are running `php artisan migrate` on your host, not in a container.  But your host does not know what `pgcontainer` means - Docker resolves containers by name, but your host can't.

You should be running `php artisan <anything>` from inside the container where PHP/Laravel is, for eg:

```
docker exec your_laravel_container_name php artisan migrate
```

This way `artisan` runs *inside* the container, and host name resolution works just the same as it does for Laravel.  Do not change your `.env` or config, `artisan` is part of Laravel and needs the same config as the Laravel application itself.